# Every time pod is restarted in kube it changes permissions on .ssh folder

Tags: linux, kubernetes

Hey I need 600 on priv key and 644 on pub key permissions but any time the pod is restarted it overrites these changes - any though what is causing it? the pod itself has PVC attached to it.

my pvc

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-home
  namespace: myns
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: gold
```

and the jenkins is deployed from helm

```
helm3 show values stable/jenkins > jenkins.yaml
```

and i pretty much throw everything away for this example except

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: jenkins-home
```

i create dir /var/jenkins_home/.ssh and put my keys in it, anytime after deployment you delete the pod and new one is spawned - the permissions change

Comment: where .ssh folder is located? in the pod or on your host?

Comment: Can you provide some context. Maybe the deployment yaml? Dome info about the container image you are using?

Comment: using custom image and the yaml is `helm show values stable/jenkins > jenkins.yaml` - I have attached external pvc to that jenkins so once it starts I create /var/jenkins_home/.ssh dir put priv and pub keys in there with 600 and 644 permissions and after pod is restarted the permision jumps to 640 on bouth

Comment: in that file you would only enable persistance at the bottom and write the name of pvc